# How to encrypt the password for remmina command line use

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, remmina

When I run the following command,

> echo "testing123" | remmina --encrypt-password

I get the following error Unknown option --encrypt-password

I want to encrypt the password and add it to the .remmina file, But not able to encrypt it correctly.

And I tried the following python code also, It is not working.

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

secret = base64.encodestring('this_is_my_secret_code')
password = base64.encodestring('passwordAQZWX')

print secret
print password

print DES3.new(secret, DES3.MODE_CBC, secret).encrypt(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:
`DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS= remmina --encrypt-password <<< "password"`

More info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/665423/remmina-rdp-connection-from-bash-without-encrypting-password-or-creating-profile

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1163204)

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! While this link might answer the question, it is better to explain what exactly you are referring to as the linked site might change rendering your answer useless.